# Key-value dictionary in bash 4 wrongly thinks it has a key

Tags: bash, dictionary, key-value

I want to store key-values to store addresses of people.

The following code builds a bash 4 array, puts a key-value, then tries to get the value for a (non-existing) key:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A addresses
addresses["john doe"]="Cows street 67"

containsElement () {
  local e
  for e in "${@:2}"; do [[ "$e" == "$1" ]] && return 0; done
  return 1
}

NAME="ian nothere"
containsElement "${NAME}" "${addresses[@]}"
if [[ $? -eq 1 ]]; then
  echo "Address is known: "
  echo ${addresses[${NAME}]}
else
  echo "Address unknown"
fi
```

Unfortunately, it returns:

```
$ ./run.sh
Address is known: 

$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: err you return 1 when address is not known. seems OK to me. It should be `if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]` right?

Comment: Btw.: array `addresses` is global, no need to pass to your function.

Comment: Also, you are checking values, not keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of problems in this bash file, plus I admit I'm currently unable to pass the dictionary as a parameter. BUT globally this is wrong:

- you loop through the dictionary to find the values: not the principle of a dictionary, and really not performant. Make it 200000 entries you'll see it's darn slow with a `O(n)` implementation, but it shouldn't.
- you really don't need a loop to see if present, since you retrieve the value eventually!

Alternative: just retrieve the value and check if empty

simplified version with the name as parameter:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A addresses
addresses["john doe"]="Cows street 67"
addresses["freddy"]="Cat street 23"

NAME=$1

r=${addresses[${NAME}]}
if [ -z "$r" ] ; then
  echo "Address unknown"
else
  echo "Address is known: $r"
  echo 
fi
```

test:

```
$ dict.sh "john doe"
Address is known: Cows street 67
$ dict.sh "john doeff"
Address unknown
```

Comment: see my updated answer. I hope you'll like the radical change of style :)